# AccessibilityService Event types - Can it be configured dynamically?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I have an app that uses accessibiityService API, and right now I'm configuring it via an xml config file.

The file ofcourse contains the event types I'm interested in, But I wonder if I can set those up in runtime?

If so, can someone show me the way or give a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AccessibilityService#getServiceInfo, AccessibilityService#setServiceInfo, and change AccessibilityServiceInfo.eventTypes.